# read ECONNRESET using expo build

Tags: android, react-native, build, expo

I am building an apk for my application which is built by react native using expo
I use  `expo build:android` command in the terminal and after this I got a prompt to choose from:

```
? Would you like to upload a keystore or have us generate one for you?
If you don't know what this means, let us handle it! :)
```

so i choosed that expo will handle it and I got the following steps

```
Publishing to channel 'default'...
Building iOS bundle
Building Android bundle
Analyzing assets
Uploading assets
Uploading \assets\alert.mp3
Uploading \assets\images\splash.png
Uploading \assets\images\icon.png
```

and then I got the follwing error

```
read ECONNRESET
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

I also updated expo-cli to the latest version!
and here is my app.json if it helps

```
 {
  "expo": {
    "name": "app name",
    "slug": "app-name",
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "scheme": "myapp",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.el3ameed.appname",
      "versionCode": 1,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#171717"
      }
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.el3ameed.appname",
      "buildNumber": "1.0.0"
    },
    "description": ""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're on Windows because I faced the exact same issue. 
So first verify that you've followed the instructions given here:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/building-standalone-apps/
Especially regarding installing Ubuntu and enabling WSL (in that order).

I was getting this error even after following the instructions so what worked for me was disabling my Windows Firewall. After that it worked like a charm.

Also as a last resort try using a VPN as that worked for me aswell.

Comment: I tried all above except the vpn but also it didn't work
i'll try to use vpn and inform you 
thanks

Comment: Thanks, It works! 
but unfortunately I get another error related to an asset I'll post a question with it

thanks again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61164119/error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-expo-av

if you could help!