# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory expo-av

Tags: react-native, audio, build, expo

I'm building an application using react-native with expo-cli and I'm building the apk using the command:

```
expo build:android
```

but I get the error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Ahmed Hassan\Desktop\app-name\assets\sounds\alert.mp3'
```

regarding the asset I'm importing in a component with the following code:

```
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';

    async function sound() {
      const soundObject = new Audio.Sound();
      try {
        await soundObject.loadAsync(require('../assets/sounds/alert.mp3'));
        await soundObject.playAsync();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
```

Comment: This similar issue might help:
https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/1634

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem as my app.json doesn't contain those two lines

Comment: {
  "expo": {
    "name": "app name",
    "slug": "app-name",
    "privacy": "public",
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ],
    "sdkVersion": "37.0.0",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "scheme": "myapp",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.package.name",
      "versionCode": 1
    },
    "description": " "
  }
}

Comment: I was facing the same issue as you, but I've found the solution : [ERROR:ENOENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61338639/works-in-debug-but-not-in-release-expo-av-react-native-unimodules/61349193#61349193)