# Works in debug but not in release | expo-av | react-native-unimodules

Tags: react-native, debugging, expo, release

### Environment

Expo CLI 3.11.1 environment info:
    System:
      OS: Windows 10
    Binaries:
      Yarn: 1.22.4 - C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD
      npm: 6.12.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: Version  3.6.0.0 AI-192.7142.36.36.6308749

**React-native android on device**

## Step to repro :

### 1.

```
npx react-native init ReactRelease --version 0.62.2
npm install react-native-unimodules@0.9.0 --save 
expo install expo-av
```

### 2.

Configure your files according to the doc in each library

### 3.

Edit **App.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';

var audioObjectActions = new Audio.Sound();

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {};
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.AUDIO_RECORDING);
        await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
            staysActiveInBackground: true,
            allowsRecordingIOS: false,
            interruptionModeIOS: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_IOS_DUCK_OTHERS,
            playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
            playThroughEarpieceAndroid: false,
            interruptionModeAndroid: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_ANDROID_DUCK_OTHERS,
            shouldDuckAndroid: true
        });
    }

    async _playRandomAction() {
        try {
            audioObjectActions.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(this._onPlaybackStatusUpdateAction);
            await audioObjectActions.loadAsync(require('./assets/song_sound.m4a'));
            await audioObjectActions.playAsync();
        } catch (error) {
            Alert.alert('ERROR : ', '' + JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    }

    _onPlaybackStatusUpdateAction = async (playbackStatus) => {
        if (!playbackStatus.isLoaded) {
            // Update your UI for the unloaded state
            if (playbackStatus.error) {
                console.log(`Encountered a fatal error during playback: ${playbackStatus.error}`);
                // Send Expo team the error on Slack or the forums so we can help you debug!
            }
        } else {
            if (playbackStatus.didJustFinish && !playbackStatus.isLooping) {
                await audioObjectActions.stopAsync();
                await audioObjectActions.unloadAsync();
            }
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text> Test Audio </Text>
                <Button title="On joue le morceau" onPress={async () => this._playRandomAction()} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#555555'
    }
});
```

### 4.

Create assets folder and add song_sound.m4a like this :
[image: bug]

### 5

**Connect your android device via USB**

### Test in **debug** :

```
//POWERSHELL 1
npx react-native run-android   

//POWERSHELL 2
npm start
```

#### Behavior

Works perfectly : the sound is loaded and is played

### Test in **release**

```
cd android 
./gradlew assembleRelease
./gradlew installRelease
```

#### Behavior

The sound doesn't load and the error displayed is :

```
{
    "nativeStackAndroid":[],
    "userInfo":null,
    "message":"com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource$FileDataSourceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets_song_sound: open fialed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)",
    "code":"E_LOAD_ERROR",
    "line": 18,
    "column": 1111,
    "sourceURL":"index.android.bundle"
}
```

## What I want ?

**Just load and play an audio in release juste like in debug.**

Comment: I've also tried to put the audio file in android\app\src\main\res\raw, but the same error persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer.

## How it works

```js
require()
```

not works well in release.

---

I don't know why **require()** works well in release with **Image** but not with **Audio**

So you need to use

```js
{ uri: 'asset:/my_sound.m4a' }
```

and put your sound file (like my_sound.m4a) in android/app/src/main/assets:
[image: FOLDER STRUCTURE]

And it will work.

Comment: I added the unimodules for expo-av in my bare project and it is working fine on dev but release apk is not even launching.

Comment: Is there a way for getting this to work on expo managed project?